# persistent sessions with passport, mongodb and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm using passport to handle authentication and sessions in my application. I'm persisting sessions to mongodb using mongostore.

The setup works fine in general. However, when I restart the server all users are logged out, so apparently sessions are hold in memory instead of being only persisted to mongodb. I'm trying to achieve a setup where users are still logged in when restarting the server.

Basic configuration is as follows

## middleware

```
    app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session({
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
        store: new MongoStore(
            {
                db: mongodb.Db(
                    conf.mongodbName,
                    new mongodb.Server(
                        'localhost',
                        27017,
                        {
                            auto_reconnect: true,
                            native_parser: true
                        }
                    ),
                    {
                        journal: true
                    }
                )
            },
            function(error) {
                if(error) {
                    return console.error('Failed connecting mongostore for storing session data. %s', error.stack);
                }
                return console.log('Connected mongostore for storing session data');
            }
        )
    }));
```

## passport

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        console.log('user %s attempting to authenticated', email);
        return User.findOne({email:email}, function(error, user) {
            if(error) {
                console.error('Failed saving user %s. %s', user.id, error.stack);
                return done(error);
            }
            if(!user) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            console.log('user %s logged in successfully', user.id);
            return done(null, { //passed to callback of passport.serializeUser
                id : user.id
            });
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user.id); //this is the 'user' property saved in req.session.passport.user
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    return User.findOne({ id: id }, function (error, user) {
        return done(error, user);
    });
});
```

## github repo (including all code necessary to run code)

I created a barebone github repo including the code [here](https://github.com/forste/passport-persistent-sessions)

just create a conf.js file in the root directory with your mongodb credentials, i.e. mongodbURL and mongodbName, run npm install and node app.js to get started.

thanks

Comment: Not actually writing data to disk is what makes mongodb web scale ;-)  See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs

Answer (score 31):

`passport.session()` doesn't take any configuration, as of Express version 4.X it's `session()` you need to configure:

```
app.use(session({
  cookie : {
    maxAge: 3600000 // see below
  },
  store : new MongoStore(...)
});
...
app.use(passport.session());
```

Also, `maxAge` (which should be a property of `cookie`) doesn't take a `Date` argument, but just the number of milliseconds a session should be valid.

For instructions on using the express middleware module session, you can find out more [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session).