# How to save sessions to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I'm using express(node.js) and `express-session` package to manage sessions. But I want to save sessions to my Mongo database so when I reboot my server, users don't have to log in again.

Comment: are you currently using _passport.js_?. share your code.

Comment: @KPal no, I'm not. I dont know what is passport.js

Comment: Then read about the _passport.js_ and how to use it in your _node_ application and it could do work you are looking for. after that check out this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061891/7735091] answer for solving your issue. If you share your code then I could help you more.

Comment: @KPal thanks, I will search about passport.js